# Different EDMX model is created on run

Tags: .net, entity-framework, edmx

I have a third-party project (say DataProject) with EF data context defined and also EDMX files in it. I also have my own project (say MyProject) that is referencing to the DataProject so I can use its data context.

When I reference MyProject to the DataProject directly within a solution everything is working well. The EDMX files in MyProject/*bin*/Debug/EDMX are exactly same as in the DataProject/EDMX/.

But I need MyProject to use DataProject as a NuGet package. So I add it as a NuGet reference and while it's being added I notice that a EDMX folder is appearing under the MyProject main folder. The EDMX files in this folder are same as in the DataProject/EDMX. So far so good.

But when I **build** and run MyProject, it creates MyProject/*bin*/Debug/EDMX with files of a different version than in any of above and I cannot run datacontext due to "The current model no longer matches the model used to pre-generate the mapping views..." error. I'm not sure why this happens - is it context and EDMX files mismatch or anything else. I just know that if I reference MyProject to the DataProject directly in a solution then everything works well.

1. Why does MyProject create different EDMX files when I'm referencing to DataProject as a NuGet package? Why it creates same files when referencing directly to the DataProject?
2. Is there a way to ignore the error above?
3. Is there a way to force EF context use specific EDMX file?
4. Is there a file/config where should I check any settings?
5. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the reason. The Edmx files generated for the schema are out of date but they correspond to the database schema. When I was referencing directly to the DataProject, the EDMX files are copied into the /bin/Debug/Edmx as-is because they are set as "Content", "Copy if newer".
When I reference to the DataProject via NuGet, the files in the MyProject/Edmx are automatically set as "Emtityeploy", "DoNotCopy" - so they are never copied to the /bin/Debug, instead the new Edmx files are generated on build. These Edmx files match to the EF model but are too new for the database which match to the original Edmx files.